# How to call a method when clicking on href on jsp(Using portlet JSR 286 and Spring MVC 3)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet, jsr286

i am new to portlet and I have a visit.jsp page with an href tag as follows:

```
<a href="www.randomUrl.com">Visit ....</a>
```

Basically my requirement is that i just have to call a method called `methodVisit` in a `VisitController.java` when i click on the href and return back to visit.jsp.
Then in my `methodVisit`  add an attribute called isVisited to my model and return to my visit.jsp page 
so my method will have the following line i guess:

```
VisitController.java
public .. methodVisit(...){
model.addAttribute("isVisited", isVisited));
}
```

Then when i return on my visit.jsp page i can use this check:

```
<c:if test="${isVisited}"> 
Then display this line when href  is clicked from visit.jsp page
</c:if>
```

I have seen the following example when submit button is used:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="returnToSearchUrl" >
    <portlet:param name="ActController" value="returnToSearch" />
</portlet:actionURL>


    <input type="button" class="button" value='<spring:message code="button.returSearch" />' onclick="self.location='${returnToSearchUrl}'"/>




@ActionMapping(params = "ActController=returnToSearch")
    public void returnToSearch(){

    ......
    }
```

However no example when using the href one, any advice how to do it with href please?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/methodVisit">Click here!</a>

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/pathtoyourproject")
public class VisitController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/methodVisit")
public ModelAndView methodVisit(...){
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndVew();
...
mav.addAttribute("isVisited", isVisited);
...
mav.setViewName("visit.jsp");
return mav;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Ajax and update the link once the Ajax request is completed?

```
var visitLink = $("a:contains('Visit')");
$(visitLink).click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
                    url:"www.randomUrl.com",
                    success: function() {
                    $(visitLink).hide();
                }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```